# Resize dragger on HTML input element just like on textarea element

Tags: html, forms, input, cross-browser, resize

Is it possible to have a resize dragger on input elements just like there is on textarea elements by default (by resize dragger I mean the little area on the bottom right corner where you can click and hold in order to resize the textarea box)?

I tried to add 'resize:both;' to the styles of the input element, with no success (see [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rd3zmohe/)):

```
<input type="text" />
```

With the CSS:

```
input {resize: both;}
```

I would be looking for an script-less solution, only relying on HTML and / or CSS, ideally crossbrowser.

Comment: question is not clear. what do you exactly want

Answer (score 0):

`resize: both;` should work as long as `overflow` is not set to `visible` (and the browser supports it!).

For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize

Comment: I can't have this working with only resize (and even setting overflow to something else, such as 'hidden')

Comment: Yeah, it would appear that `resize: both;` does not work on `input` elements, I've modified your fiddle to show the exact same CSS working on a `div`: http://jsfiddle.net/zLcr7ba5/. My best guess is that support for `resize` is spotty and `input` elements are not currently supported.

Comment: So if I want such a feature on a form field, I guess I should use a textarea, even if the input would be small, right?

Comment: I guess that is one way of achieving it, although personally I would probably go down the JavaScript route.

Comment: any suggestion / resources on how / where to start on the JS route?

Comment: In the past I've used jQueryUI and its resizable method http://jqueryui.com/resizable/. I think it works on input boxes and should offer better cross browser support than the CSS `resize` property.